# How to stop logging all debug statements in tomcat server

Tags: java, spring, tomcat, logging, tomcat5.5

I have a Tomcat 5.5  container in dedicated private virtual server. Previously I have hosted struts1,struts2, servlet based applications and all works well. Now hosted a spring 3.2 mvc application and saw it generates huge debug statements in the stdout file only for spring application and file size increases. Any suggestion would be appreciated to stop generating the debug statements except errors.

Thanks.

Comment: For your tomcat logs, are you using anything other than the default?

Comment: What logging library do you use with Spring? And by stdout file you mean Catalina.out?

Comment: have not used any logging library till now. but only included log4j.jar file in project. @Gergely when I start deploying my application the stdout file inside tomcat/logs folder increases drastically and upto 150 mb in few seconds. Just downloaded into my local machine and saw only info and debug statements are there . Please note that the generates statements are before running the application.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Create a `logging.properties` file in your application's `WEB-INF/classes` folder with the following content:

```
handlers = 1spring.org.apache.juli.FileHandler, java.util.logging.ConsoleHandler        

1spring.org.apache.juli.FileHandler.level = SEVERE

1spring.org.apache.juli.FileHandler.directory = ${catalina.base}/logs
1spring.org.apache.juli.FileHandler.prefix = springframework.

java.util.logging.ConsoleHandler.level = SEVERE  
java.util.logging.ConsoleHandler.formatter = java.util.logging.SimpleFormatter      

org.springframework.handlers = 1spring.org.apache.juli.FileHandler, java.util.logging.ConsoleHandler
```

- [Useful reference](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-6.0-doc/logging.html)

Comment: Thanks @jibbyi . It works perfectly. Supreme answer. :)

Comment: Happy to help! If you wouldn't mind marking the answer as correct, I would appreciate it!

Comment: Yes , did it. Thanks dear.

Comment: Hi Zeet, an accepted answer will have a checkmark underneath the vote tally. I suspect what you did was upvote the answer, which is great! If you could also mark it as accepted with a checkmark, that would be even better.

Comment: :) never used this before. Thanks for the knowledge :)

Comment: Hi Jibbyj. I have another server with tomcat 9 with other web application built in spring 4.x .  But this code does not help. Do I need to add/ edit something on the above code. Thanks in advance.

Comment: What is the behaviour you're observing?

Comment: It prints all debug statements in the log file inside the tomcat log folder.

Comment: Check what classes are generating the log statements, you just need to give those classes a handler. If it's something other than org.springframework, then you need to add to or modify the config above to assign a handler to that domain. The line to work off of is org.springframework.handlers = ...

Comment: On the second application I have not included the log4j xml file and dtd file. After including them all work well with Jibbyj's code.